# question about TensorFlow mnist data reshape question

Tags: tensorflow

now I'm learning TensorFlow, I wonder why numpy.swapaxes(0,3) required.

I know that result is (1, 14, 14, 5) means [ 15element[ 145element[ 145element[ 5element ] ] ] ]

and after bumpy.swapaxes(3,0) -> (5, 14, 14, 1) and 5 images.

below is my code, please save my question. thank you.

```
#load mnist data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

#get only 1 image & reshape it
img = mnist.train.images[0].reshape(28,28)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

#reshape image to get color = 1
img = img.reshape(-1,28,28,1)

#filter 3X3, count = 5
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 1, 5], stddev=0.01))

                                                 #zero-padded USE
conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d(img, W1, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
print(conv2d)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#make convoultion data
conv2d_img = conv2d.eval()

#print converted images
conv2d_img = np.swapaxes(conv2d_img, 0, 3)
for i, one_img in enumerate(conv2d_img):
plt.subplot(1,5,i+1), plt.imshow(one_img.reshape(14,14), cmap='gray')

#pooling
pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2d, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[
                    1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
print(pool)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
pool_img = pool.eval()

#print pooling image
pool_img = np.swapaxes(pool_img, 0, 3)
for i, one_img in enumerate(pool_img):
plt.subplot(1,5,i+1), plt.imshow(one_img.reshape(7, 7), cmap='gray')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swapping is necessary because it changes the order of the image channel.

By default, **TensorFlow uses NHWC**, where C = 1 since we have a grayscale image.

Therefore, you need the number of channels (1 for a grayscale image, 3 for an RGB) to be on the last axis in your data.

In your code, you can see that the `NHWC` relation holds (5 for number of images == batch_size, 14 for height, 14 for width, and 1 for image channel).